# Embeded specific div content of External URL in wicket framework

Tags: javascript, java, wicket, wicketstuff

I want to get content of a `<div>` from external URL, using Wicket, in a tooltip or titlem using `AttributeModifier` constructor.

In the external URL page source I have `<div id="bodyContent">...</div>`.

How can I display this content in wicket tooltip?

I have gone through the wicket URL for sourcing external content.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Sourcing+External+Content

but I want specific div content of external url.

Comment: I think you should parse the content from the external URL, maybe using jsoup or similar tooling. Or perhaps you can solve it in javascript entirely (using ajax, jquery)

Comment: I would use a custom Model for the AttributeModifier which fetches the external URL when get() is invoked.